# Cannot import database using PhpMyAdmin with Cpanel on a VPS?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, vps, whm

I have a recently set up VPS with cPanel.

I've made a user and created a database, and now I would like to import a database onto it.

However, when I try I get the error message

**#1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'database'**

I suspect that this can be fixed with WHM, but I do not feel like trial and error just yet.
How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: What do you mean by **import**? Is the error through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: phpmyadmin's import option. You upload your database and it gets inserted into the one you're currently in - at least that's usually the case. For some reason phpmyadmin tries to create a new database this time.

Comment: That's because the file you're attempting to import has a line to create the database. The file you're attempting to import probably has something that you don't have permissions for. I would check permissions, then the file you're importing.

Comment: I have root access to the database - unless you mean something else?

Comment: Please update your answer with the output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR user`. [Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html).

Comment: njk, you got it right in your second response. Just had to edit the mysql file and needed to remove the queries indicating a new database was to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a database using phpMyAdmin, normally you do so by importing a text file with a `.sql` extension. Here is a section of code that may be in a .sql database backup. In your example, the database you are trying to import is named database.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.9.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 02, 2010 at 08:01 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.81
-- PHP Version: 5.2.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

CREATE DATABASE database;
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
`column1` text NOT NULL,
`column2` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When using phpMyAdmin to attempt to import such a file, you will receive an error message similar to:

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE DATABASE database;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'database'
```

In this scenario, the cPanel username is `user`. Because of cPanel's database naming conventions, all database names must begin with the cPanel username followed by `_`.  Using this format you can only creat a database named `user_database`.

The reason this import failed is because of the following line in the .sql file...

```
CREATE DATABASE database;
```

Again, you cannot create a database named `database`, however you can create a database named `user_database`.

If you change the line that says: `CREATE DATABASE` so that it creates: `user_database` instead of `database` it will again fail with the following message:

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE DATABASE user_database;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'user_database'
```

When using cPanel, databases must be created within the cPanel itself.

Here are the steps to correct thi sissue:

1. Create the `user_database` database within cPanel
2. Comment out the `CREATE DATABASE` command in my .sql file

   To do this, simply change:

   `CREATE DATABASE database;`

   to

   `-- CREATE DATABASE database;`

   You are simply adding `dash-dash-space` to the front of the line to comment it out so that it will not be executed.
3. Log into phpMyAdmin, access the `user_database` database, and then import as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Before dumping your database, grant full access to your new database user created in Cpanel by the same password of that user:
 `grant all on database_name.* to database_user@localhost identified by 'password';`

Then you need to modify your .sql file (can use notepad++), comment out the part where says create and use the new database:

-- Database: `dbname`
--
-- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
-- USE `dbname`;

then you should be able to import it to your Cpanel.

Answer (score -1):

To make it official...

The file you're attempting to import probably has something that you don't have permissions for. I would check permissions, then the file you're importing.